# Should I use 'build' or 'built'

Tags: tense

Which one is correct?

> 1. A friendship **build** on business is much better than a business **build** on friendship.
> 2. A friendship that is **built** on business is much better than a business that is **built** on friendship.

Comment: To the close voters and the editor, the question is not about tense but whether a noun phrase **a friendship build** or a verb should be used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How do you know? The author hasn’t exactly given us much to go on.

Answer (score 6):

The verb [**build**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/build) is used as "I build, you build, he builds..." The first sentence makes no sense that way.

There is also a noun use of **build** (same link) but the first sentence still does not work when used like that.

The *past* and *past participle* of **build** is [**built**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/built).

So the second sentence is good, but it can be shortened to

> A friendship built on business is much better than a business built on friendship.

Comment: But if we shortened it then it looks like past tense

Comment: If a friendship exists, it *was* built.

Comment: @Rocky It's a modifier by the past particle. So Weather's answer is completely fine.

Comment: But it can also be taken as a suggestion I mean that if happen would be a good thing in future.

Comment: The sentence I posted also works as a general aphorism, for a relationship that does not yet exist, i.e. is in the future.

Comment: So what verbs need this kind of sentence structure I mean are they categorise?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking now. I have answered this question, perhaps you should ask a new question. If you are asking about "A friendship that will be builded ..." or something, it can be correct to use the past or present tense for some elements of a sentence when talking about events in the future.

Comment: ...because when that future time comes, the events have *already happened*.

Comment: Then how to pick which verbs use past form/past participal form like 'is built' is past participal and 'buit' past in the above sentence

Comment: I am sorry, that is too broad, and as said I have answered the question you asked. Please ask a new question.